# EOutOfResources problem sporadically when loading forms: "not enough storage available to process this command"

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, eoutofresources

I have an application written in Delphi 7, running in about 100 different places, and only in one of them it keeps sporadically raising an `EOutOfResources` exception:

> not enough storage available to process this command

on all machines when loading some forms with a `TImage` component.

Trying to hunt down the problem, I already checked for GDI leaks using the following tools:

- [GDI View from Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html)
- GDI Objects column from Windows' Task Manager
- Number of identifiers metric on Windows' Performance Monitor (`Perfmon.msc`)

It appears that the application is not leaking GDI handles. The maximum number of GDI handles reported in the tools above was 680.

I don't think the application is leaking memory, the memory usage stays around 100 to 170 MB.

I also checked a known issue with Delphi leaking entries in the Windows Atom Table, but every time the exception is raised, the Atom Table has very few records, ranging from 170 to 500.

Hunting down where the exception is being thrown, as far as I could track, it appears to be in the `Graphics.pas` unit in `TBitMap.CopyImage()`, line 5343:

> ```pascal
> NewHandle := CopyBitmap(AHandle, APalette, NewPalette, DIB, FCanvas);
> ```

`CopyBitmap()` is called inside `TBitmap.CopyImage()`, and I think the exception is thrown in the following code, line 5116:

> ```pascal
> Result := GDICheck(CreateDIBSection(ScreenDC, BI^, DIB_RGB_COLORS, BitsMem, 0, 0));
> ```

At least this is what Eurekalog is telling me:

> [image: Eurekalog Stack Trace]

Since this problem is occurring for this particular client, and is not very frequent, I suspected the antivirus program (Panda Dome) - so I placed the EXE in its exceptions list to see if that could be the problem, but no response from the user yet.

Does anyone have some advice to help me solve this issue?

Comment: What does the `Message` of the exception actually say? `GDICheck()` grabs the actual error code for WHY the GDI API failed, and asks the OS to format that into a human-readable message. Just looking at the class name `EOutOfResources` alone is a little misleading. According to the MSDN docs, [`CreateDIBSection()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdibsection) fails if it is given bad parameters. That is not a resource issue.

Comment: What it the size of the image that your user is opening that causes this? You haven't shown much code but i'm guessing your application is opening JPEG image and then tries to load it into `TBitmap`. So in case if image dimensions are really large it could lead to such error.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the exception message is: not enough storage available to process this command.

Comment: @SilverWarior the user do not load the images, the images are stored in form's dfm and is loaded in `TImage`when the form is shown. The largest mage is a background image with 1024 x 640 31KB, the others are just small images.

Comment: @DiegoMedeiros Do you have the same problem if you don't store such a large image in the DFM at all, but instead save it in a separate resource and load it into the `TImage` yourself after the Form is created?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I haven't tried that yet, but I am running out of ideas. I will do it then.

Comment: Don't underestimate using [the right Q tag and reading existing Q&As with that tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eoutofresources). Don't use screenshots for code.